# Why is my iframe overflow scroll not working in iOS?

Tags: html, css, ios, iframe

I write this code in my HTML and CSS, it's working flawlessly in Android devices but NOT IN iOS. Can anyone help me with my code?

HTML

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
<div>
<iframe src="https://linkhere.com"
allowfullscreen SameSite="None" secure></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.iframe-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 500%;
  position: relative;
}
.iframe-container iframe {
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
/* 4x3 Aspect Ratio */
.iframe-container-4x3 {
  padding-top: 75%;
}
.iframe-error iframe {
  border: 0;
  height: 0%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;
}
```

Issue: Cannot scroll in iframe in iPhone and Unable to display properly in iPhone

Feel free to correct me. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: what happens when you remove `overflow: hidden;` from the container?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried, it's still the same. It's scrollable but it's not display correctly like how it can with the same size screen for Android. I suspect its the div, I have to add some CSS variables into the div, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Try changing your width from 100% to 100vw in the `.iframe-container iframe` and then if that doesnt work try adding `width: 100vw;` directly into the `.iframe-container` Let me know if this works and if it doesn't let me know what happened.

Comment: Hi there, sorry for not replying, it's been super busy weeks for me. Adding width: 100vw; to the iframe container and iframe still did not display the notes at the right size. The words and pictures still stretch across to the right.